# CodedUI issue with Telerik RadRibbonBar

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests, telerik-radribbonbar

I am using RadRibbonBar in my c# winform application, i have StartMenuItems in StartMenu, Also i have 4 tabs in ribbon. I am using Coded UI to test the application. I am facing following two issues :

1. I am facing issue while selecting the StartMenu of the ribbon. CodedUI selects the items present in start menu when i select the StartMenu.
2. My second issue is with the tab of ribbon bar. When i select the tab in CodedUI, it shows the index number of the tab in Name field of the CodedUI search.

Eg. i have tab named File, which is the first tab of ribbon, when i select this control, coded UI shows 0 instead of its name.